# How to make a variable in constructor available in all methods?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am usign codeigniter and in one of my models constructor i have the following

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $DB2 = $this->load->database('std', TRUE);
}
```

and in my methods :

```
public function get_users_groups($id=FALSE)
    {
        $this->trigger_events('get_users_group');

        //if no id was passed use the current users id
        $id || $id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');

        return $DB2->select($this->tables['users_groups'].'.'.$this->join['groups'].' as id, '.$this->tables['groups'].'.name, '.$this->tables['groups'].'.description')
                        ->where($this->tables['users_groups'].'.'.$this->join['users'], $id)
                        ->join($this->tables['groups'], $this->tables['users_groups'].'.'.$this->join['groups'].'='.$this->tables['groups'].'.id')
                        ->get($this->tables['users_groups']);
    }
```

I get an undefined variable $DB2 can some tell me what i am doing wrog plase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$DB2 will only be available in the constructor scope, it needs to be a class property like below:

```
class Whatever
{
    protected $DB2;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->DB2 = $this->load->database('std', TRUE);
    }

    public function get_users_groups($id=FALSE)
    {
      // other code    
      $this->DB2->select( ....
      // other code
    }

}
```

Comment: To clarify, a class refers to its members and functions using `$this`, as in `$this->memberVariable` and `$this->classFunction()`.  It's something that took a little getting used to coming from other programming languages, where `this` is implicit.